# Two questions asking the same thing with different answers.

Tags: probability, permutations

I was given two questions:

> If 8 identical blackboards are to be divided among 4 schools, how many divisions are possible?

and

> Suppose 8 new teachers are to be divided among 4 schools. How many divisions are possible?

Although the questions seem exactly the same to me, except for the fact that the blackboards are identical and the teachers are not, they are given two completely different approaches to answering.

The answer to the blackboards question is the following,
$$
\frac{11!}{8!3!}
$$

while the answer to the teachers question is,
$$
4^8
$$

While I understand that when something is identical, the probability greatly decreases, I still can't understand why such a different approach is used. What is the cause of this?

Comment: Questions written in natural language can often be ambiguous since you are expected to make some assumptions and, hopefully, the same assumptions are the setter made.  In this case, as Vasily explains, you are expected to assume that the blackboards are indistinguishable or at least insignificantly different but that the teachers are distinguishable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose two blackboards are divided among two schools, Alpha and Beta. Three scenarios are possible:

- Alpha gets 0, Beta gets 2
- Alpha gets 1, Beta gets 1
- Alpha gets 2, Beta gets 0

Suppose two teachers Alice and Bob are divided among two schools, Alpha and Beta:

- Alpha gets none, Beta gets Alice and Bob
- Alpha gets Alice, Beta gets Bob
- Alpha gets Bob, Beta gets Alice
- Alpha gets Alice and Bob, Beta gets none

Different approach is used because you can't easily go from identical objects to non-identical or vice versa. In this example, the situations when all the blackboards go to the same school is exactly the same as the situations when teachers go to the same school. However, when blackboards go to dirrerent school, you need to divide by 2! in comparison to the teachers. In other words for teachers the number of ways is:
$ T = 1 + 2 + 1$. For blackboards, $B = 1 + 2/2! + 1$. When there are more schools and teachers/blackboards, there are more terms that are divided by different coefficients. Thus, you need separate approaches to count permutations of identical and non-identical objects